# How to show from the definition of topological space that the topology $\tau$ is the family of open sets of a topology with a filter base?

Tags: general-topology, proof-explanation

I am starting with the given definitions

1. A filter $ \mathcal{F}$ on $X$ is a family of subsets of      $X$ such that

   - $\varnothing \not\in \mathcal{F}.$
   - $\mathcal{F}$ is algebraically closed under finite           intersections
   - $ \mathcal{F} $ is an upper family.
2. A neigbhourhood structure $ \mathcal{N} $ on a set $X$ is  an assignment to each $x \in X$ of a filter $ \mathcal{N}(x) $     on X all of whose elements contain the point $x$. The pair   $(X, \mathcal{N})$ is called a **neighbourhood space**;     The filter $ \mathcal{N}(x)$ called the neighbourhood filter   of the point $x$ in $X$.
3. A set $T \subset X$ is **open** if, and only if, for all $x \in T$, there exists $N \in \mathcal N(x)$ such that $N \subset A$
4. A **filter base** $ \mathcal{B} $ is a family of non-empty    subsets of $X$ such that if $A,B \in \mathcal{B}$ there exist   $C \in \mathcal{B} $ then there exists $C \in \mathcal{B}$     such that $C \subset A \cap B$.
5. A non-empty collection $ \mathcal{B} $ of subsets of $X$   is a base for a specific filter $ \mathcal{F} $ on $X$    if and only if

   - $ \mathcal{B} \subset \mathcal{F}$
   - If $ A \in \mathcal{F}$, there exists $ B \in \mathcal{B}$ such that $ B \subset A$.
6. A **topological space** is a neighbourhood space $( X, \mathcal{N})$      in which, for all $x \in X$ and for all $ N \in \mathcal{N} $,    there exists $N_1 \in \mathcal{N}(x)$ such that, for all      $y \in N_1 , N\in \mathcal{N}(y)$.

**Theorem 1** : A neighbourhood space $( X, \mathcal N)$ is  a **topological space** if and only if each filter $ \mathcal N(x)$ has a filter base consisting of open sets.

The proof of this theorem starting with the definition of **topological space**
can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1674013)

Now, one can also speak of this theorem,

**Theorem 2** : Let $\tau$ be any family of subsets of a set $X$ that satisfies the three conditions:

1. $\varnothing$ and $X$ belong to $\tau$
2. an arbitrary union of elements of $\tau$ belongs to $\tau$.
3. any finite intersection of elements of $\tau$ belongs to $\tau$

Then $\tau$ is the family of open sets of a topology on $X$ with  a neighbourhood base $\mathcal B(x) :=\{O \in \tau | x \in O\}$ for all $x$ in $X$.

Here the filter base $\mathcal B(x)$ generates the neighbourhood
filter $\mathcal N(x)$ at $x \in X$.

**I want to prove theorem 2 starting either from definition-6 or theorem-1.**

I know certain things as -

- I only know whether a subset of $X$ is open or not only from the definition-3.
- An arbitrary union and finite intersection of open sets is an open set.
- Closer under finite intersection is a property of filters. (Here the Neighbourhood
  filters $\mathcal N(x)$ which are generated by the filter base $\mathcal B(x)$)
- $\forall x \in X, $ $X \in \mathcal B(x)$, and $\varnothing \not\in \mathcal B(x)$ (by definition)

I want to prove that the sets $O \in \tau $ are open as per the definition-3 of open sets

**How, to go from here as the proof is concerned?**

Comment: I think [my answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2771383/4280) will be of interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s immediate from the definition: if $U\in\tau$ and $x\in U$, then $U\in\mathscr{B}(x)\subseteq\mathscr{N}(x)$, and certainly $U\subseteq U$, so $U$ is open in the sense of (3). Of course to use **Theorem 1** to prove **Theorem 2** you still have to show that each $\mathscr{B}(x)$ really is a filter base, but that’s very straightforward.